# Grocery, Product input, weight by price

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-options

I'm looking for my Magento store like bigbasket.com
I'm trying to add weight to price but I'm unable to get same as bigbasket.com and I need some solution about how to create an attribute for grocery products and how to manage weights by price?

For reference I just sending this URL (https://www.bigbasket.com/pd/10000404/bb-royal-sona-masoori-raw-rice-10-kg-bag/) please this and let me know the weighting process for grocery

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create few simple products,one for each weight to price type.
Now create a configurable product or group product from these simple products.

Once done you should then tweak block code and .phtml to get values and display.

As if you look at the reference URL you gave then that display can be considered as a modification of configurable product in Magento.

Comment: Thanks for replying me,  Basically I'm a new one to Magento so have little bit confusion. Now I'm going to create products with the same name and different sizes using simple Products. Then What is Tweak Block Code?? on .phtml??

Comment: Yes.You have configurable product "rice" and simple products "rice 2kg" and "rice 4kg". In the configurable product, you have associated products, which link the simple to the configurable. By using the "configurable by" you get to select what "size" (weight) you want to buy.

tweak the block code.phtml requires someone with coding experience in order to get the products to display as radio buttons, instead of the default drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding some Rice names but how to configurable products?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html  link explains how to create configurable product and concept.Basically you have a configurable product 'rice' created from simple product 'rice 1kg' with size attribute  as 1kg another one 'rice 5kg' with size attribute as 5kg.So when you create rice then in drop down you will have 1kg and 5kg as drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like product configuration with a single attribute.

You'll need an attribute that you can "use to create configurable product". We use one called "size" and it has a massive amount of options. "1 kg" and "25 kg" are examples of those options.

When creating a configurable product, you'll be able to select what it's "configurable by". Your attributes that you select to be  "use to create configurable product" will show up on the second "add product" step for you to select. (note: you can't change these once your configurable product is created).

Each simple product associated with that configurable product will carry a unique instance of "size" and carry their own price.

Once the product family is set up, you'll need something that switches between the prices on the product page (I remember people using simple configurable products extension, but that might have been added into magento by now).